# Como separar una cadena cada n caracteres en java

Tags: java

Quiero hacer que esta función, que imprime una matriz, me lo devuelva como un string. Se me ha ocurrido ir almacenando los valores en un String y cada n-filas que tenga la matriz, me meta un salto de línea (\n), pero no me funciona. ¿Alguien sabe como?

```
public static String imprimeArray(char[][] arr) 
{   
   String inicio = "";
   String res = "";
   byte comienzo = 0;

   for (byte i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
   {
      for (byte j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) 
      {
         inicio += arr[i][j] + " ";
      }             
   }
        
   for (byte i = 0; i < res.length(); i++) 
   {
      res = inicio.substring(i + 5) + "\n";
   }
        
   return res + "|";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer uso del método [String.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char%5B%5D))
el cual convierte un array de tipo char en un String,para una matriz solo necesitaria recorrerlo con un for

```
public static String imprimeArray(char[][] arr) {
       String res="";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                res+=String.valueOf(arr[i])+"\n"; //agregas salto de linea               
        }     
        return res;
    }
}
```

[prueba del metodo](https://rextester.com/SNURL6352)

Answer (score 0):

Separar una cadena cada n caracteres:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=3;//Indice separador
    String cadena="separaremos esta cadena",arreglo="";
    cadena=cadena.replace(" ",""); //Quitamos los espacios en blanco
    //Anular la linea anterior si se quiere contar los espacios en blanco

    char[] letras=cadena.toCharArray();
    //convierte el String en una matriz de char ,inclutendo los espacios en blanco si los hay
    
    for (int j = 1; j<=letras.length; j++){
        arreglo=arreglo+ letras[j-1] ;
       if(j%n==0)arreglo=arreglo+" "; //Introducimos un espacio para separar cada 3 letras
    }
    System.out.print(arreglo); 
}
```

EXTRA:
Aqui imprimimos cualquier matriz de 2 dimensiones pasando cada valor a un String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] n = {{2,4,4},{6,6,9},{8,10,12}}; //Ejemplo
    String arreglo="";
    //Imprimir los valores del arreglo 
    for (int i = 0; i <n.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <n[i].length; j++){
            arreglo=arreglo +"   "+ n[i][j] ;
        }
        arreglo = arreglo + "\n" ;
    }
    System.out.println(arreglo);//mostrar el resultado      
}
```